# 2-factor authentification not available for the AppleID to turn on

Tags: macos

I am following the instruction from Apple.com to turn on the 2-factor authentication on MacAir notebook (Catalina) and receive not available error as above when clicking the Turn on button under Password & Security in System Preferences. I notice that the iCloud icon is grey out (I don't use iCloud and don't know how to login). What is the right way to turn on two-factor authentication for developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to [Manage your Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com) website, login with your Apple ID and scroll down to Security section. You'll find the option to setup 2 Factor Authentication for your account.